# What is the name of the expression $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})^2$ to describe probability of measurements on qubits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I know that the following formula describes the probability of a qubit confirming to a measurment  in one axis, with an angle $\theta$ to another axis.
$$\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})^2$$
I have been searching the internet for the past hour for the name of this expression. I believe it was called something similar to Moslow's Law, but I cannot find it.
If someone could help me out, that'd be great!

Comment: Do you mean [Malus' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Malus.27_law_and_other_properties) by any chance?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I do.  I could not find it anywhere without knowing it's name, including with several formula searchtools. If you would submit that as answer, I could mark it as correct?

Comment: I will to prevent others clicking through, but for the record: this is a *terrible* question. $\cos^2(\theta/2)$ is an expression, which is different from a formula, and neither is a law.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It might be, but if I do not remember the name and it is Malus' Law, it hardly seems illogical I thought it was a law. Besides that I can imagine this is one of the less useful or qualitative questions on StackPhysics, but not illogical or incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you can also call it Fubini-Study metric?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because don't see how it could help anyone other than OP.

Comment: @innisfree I can see your point and but cannot delete this myself.

Comment: Hold your horses, that's just my opinion.  I presume e.g. @Emilio disagrees

Comment: @innisfree If the OP wants to delete this question I have no objections. Procedurally, the only thing that prevents it is the upvote and the accept on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean [Malus' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Malus.27_law_and_other_properties). However, it's important to note that the term not normally used in that context - it is usually reserved for the transmission characteristics of linear polarizers for classical light.